# Terraform: Trying to create a range of subnet cidrs using a list, but getting error "string required"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Created a list of ranges as per below

```
subnet_names = ["subnet-lister", "subnet-kryten", "subnet-rimmer", "subnet-cat", "subnet-holly",]
subnet_cidrs = ["192.2.128.0/18", "192.2.0.0/17", "192.2.208.0/20", "192.2.192.0/20", "192.2.224.0/20",]
```

With this in the subnets.tf

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnet" {
  name          = "${var.subnet_names}-subnet"
  ip_cidr_range = var.subnet_cidrs
  network       = var.network_name
  region        = var.subnet_region
```

And the below in variables.tf (for the module)

```
variable "subnet_names" {
  description = "The name to use for Subnet "
  type        =  list(string)
}

variable "subnet_cidrs" {
  description = "The cidr range for for Subnets"
  type        = list(string)
}
```

But getting the following message from Terraform.

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ..\..\..\Test-Modules\red\dwarf\subnets.tf line 3, in resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnet":
   3:   ip_cidr_range = var.subnet_cidrs

Inappropriate value for attribute "ip_cidr_range": string required.
```

I'm pretty new to this, can you help me work out what I am going wrong. I've seem someone else use a list for the cidr range (mind you that was for AWS). Does GCP not support this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is actually create several subnets. For that, you should use a `map` variable and a loop.

```
variable "subnets" {
    type = map(string)
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnet" {
  for_each      = var.subnets
  name          = each.key
  ip_cidr_range = each.value
  ...
}
```

Then you can provide the subnets like:

```
subnets = {
    subnet-lister = "192.2.128.0/18",
    subnet-kryten = "192.2.0.0/17",
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am not getting the error "An argument named "subnets" is not expected here."

Presuming that this should be in my main.tf (the 'subnets =' part


```

Comment: The `subnets=` part is the value of the variable you pass in. See these docs: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#assigning-values-to-root-module-variables

Comment: All working as expected now. However I have ran into a new issue, trying to output ip addresses of these subnets. 
I thought I might be able to use [0] to pull them out of their place in the list, but this does not seem to work. 
Any ideas?

Comment: It'd be easier to answer that follow-up question if posted as a separate question but the quick answer is `{ for k, s in google_compute_network.subnet : k => s.id }` where `s.id` retrieves the id of each subnet. You can use any attribute of `google_compute_network` in that way to produce a map from subnet name to the selected value.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Terraform Docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/datasource_compute_subnetwork.html), the `ip_cidr_range` takes only one CIDR-Block, not a list. So you need to create one resource per subnet like this:

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnet" {
  count = length(var.subnet_names)

  name          = "${var.subnet_names[count.index]}-subnet"
  ip_cidr_range = var.subnet_cidrs[count.index]
  network       = var.network_name
  region        = var.subnet_region

  ...
```

I would also recommend to restructure your data a bit, so you can use for_each instead of count (look at Ben's answer). This behaves better in case you later change your configuration and for example insert a new subnet, as described nicely [in this post](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9).

Comment: Slowly getting there. Now have Given value not suitable for child module on the cidr when using the website you suggested

"The given value is not suitable for child module variable "subnet_cidrs"
defined at ..\..\..\Modules\subnets\variables.tf:16,1-24: map of string
required.

Comment: Got it!
Combined the subnet list from Ben and the restructuring you suggested. Together it works!